# Is there a negation option for using Taxonomy terms in Drupal Contexts?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I have a Drupal 6 site which displays a number of blocks using Contexts. Some of these blocks are View blocks. *I need to display one View block based on a particular condition using Contexts.*

Now, its possible to make the Block appear on a story node if it has a particular taxonomy term tag. Contexts provides an easy interface to do that by displaying all the tags in the site as a list.

Now I need to do the opposite, ***I need to make the View Block appear on all story nodes except on those which contain that particular taxonomy term.*** Currently Contexts does not offer any NOT condition or any negation of the values presented in the taxonomy terms lists.

Now my question is, Is there a negation option for using Taxonomy terms in Drupal Contexts or should I resort to writing custom PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it using a workaround.

I used the Context Disable Contexts module - http://drupal.org/project/context_disable_context
and got it working.

Thanks to all who helped.